# adal.js authentication in a modal

Tags: adal

We've been venturing into the world of adal.js and have successfully deployed the demo ToDoSPA as per this:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp

Our next challenge came with the way we were using it and this resulted in us requiring the login window to show in a new window by using this code:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs#q4-i-get-this-error-refused-to-display--in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-deny

This is working well enough for us to continue to explore adal.js for our requirements. My question is, is it possible to have the login window show in a modal dialog instead of a new window? If so, how would this be achieved? Anyone with ideas, please don't hesitate to get down to basics, state the obvious, treat us like dummies, post full code etc etc - we probably need it as this is all pretty new to us! But an interesting adventure too...

If we can get this one figured out, we'll likely be back here again soon!

Many thanks

Comment: Hi @soundsessential, do you have any update for now?

Comment: Hey Gary. Sorry. Many thanks for the reply. We have successfully deployed the pop-up window, but appreciate the additional link below that I'm not sure we came across before. It seems like, from what you're saying, having the prompt open in a modal dialog instead of a new window is not something that is natively supported. If it is in the future then it's something we would be interested in. Until then we'll see if the pop up window will work for our needs. Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Model is a pure client component, you need to modify the adal for js's SDK to manually implement the iframe into a model component. It's a lot of work and not directly integration.

Although, you can use popup window to achieve your requirement. Configure `displayCall` in adal context initial function closure:

```
adalProvider.init(
        {
          displayCall: function (urlNavigate) {
                var popupWindow = window.open(urlNavigate, "login", 'width=483, height=600');
                if (popupWindow && popupWindow.focus)
                    popupWindow.focus();
                var registeredRedirectUri = this.redirectUri;
                var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
                    if (!popupWindow || popupWindow.closed || popupWindow.closed === undefined) {
                        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                    }
                    try {
                        if (popupWindow.document.URL.indexOf(registeredRedirectUri) != -1) {
                            window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                            window.location.hash = popupWindow.location.hash;
                            popupWindow.close();
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                }, 20);
            }
       },
        $httpProvider
        );
```

It will direct to Azure AD SSO page in a popup window. You can refer to https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs#q5-how-to-use-a-popup-for-loginauthentication-process for more info.